# Boost::asio::endpoint::size() and resize()

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I was reading the boost endpoint documentation and saw
size() and resize() member funcs.
the documentation says: Gets the underlying size of the endpoint in the native type.
what does this size represent and where can it be used/resized ?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs state, a `boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint` is an object that:

> describes an endpoint for a
>   version-independent IP socket.

In this case, "endpoint" usually refers to an IP address and port.  Depending on the OS *and* the protocol you're using, the "native" representation of the endpoint (the one used by the OS for the lower-level sockets API) may be different, so `basic_endpoint` serves as a wrapper for the native endpoint type.

To address your question as to what `size()` and `resize()` actually do, the answer I think is "not much," other than to serve as a portable way to get the size of the underlying endpoint representation.

On UNIX-like systems (sorry, I've no details for Windows :o), the underlying endpoint type is usually `struct sockaddr_in` for IPv4 and `struct sockaddr_in6` for IPv6 (defined in `netinet/in.h`).  So `size()` would return the `sizeof` one of those structures, depending on how the `basic_endpoint` was constructed.  For more info on the `sockaddr` family of structs, see here:  http://www.retran.com/beej/sockaddr_inman.html

In fact, the code for `size()` is surprisingly simple if you look at it (~line 180 in `boost/asio/ip/basic_endpoint.hpp`).  It merely calls `sizeof` on a `typedef` representing the underlying native endpoint type for the protocol of the instance.  Interestingly, the `resize()` method seems to do pretty much *nothing*, other than throw an exception if the requested size is greater than the size of the underlying `sockaddr_storage` struct (`sockaddr_storage` is a struct that contains enough storage space for either `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`).  It possibly exists for future use in Asio or to adapt to future protocols, since `basic_endpoint` is a templated class.  I'm not really sure...

As for why you'd want to use these methods of an endpoint object in day-to-day Asio programming, I can't really think of a reason.

Answer (score 0):

size() is probably mapped to sizeof(sockaddr_in) or or sizeof(sockaddr_in6).  Boost.Asio is a header only library so you can easily check yourself. I'm not sure what resize is for, I've never used it. What are you trying to accomplish with it?